# save data in codeigniter with array

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, codeigniter-2

I have an array recieved by the code

```
$logged_in=$this->session->userdata('logged_in');
```

In this I have an element `gid`. I want to set value in this `session` with `gid=2`. How can I set this ??

Answer (score 2):

use set_userdata() function as follows

```
$this->session->set_userdata('gid', 1);
```

if you want to set more than one value in session, use array method as follows

```
$session_array = array('gid' => 2, 'name' => 'john') ;
$this->session->set_userdata($session_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using session

```
$this->load->library('session');
$this->session->set_userdata('gid', 2);
```

To get session value

```
echo $this->session->userdata('gid'); //Output is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data=array('user_name'=>$this->input->post('user_name'),
                 'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
                 'user_password'=>md5($this->input->post('user_password')),
                 'product'=>implode(",", $this->input->post('product')),
                 'compney_name'=>$this->input->post('compney_name'),
                 'category'=>$this->input->post('category'),
                 'compney_type'=>$this->input->post('compney_type'),
                 'city'=>$this->input->post('city'),
                 'state'=>$this->input->post('state'),
                 'phone'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
                 'service_id'=>implode(",", $this->input- 
                  >post('service_id')),
                 'image'=>$this->session->userdata('images_business')
                 );
     $id = $this->session->userdata('lastid');
     $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->update('user', $data); 
     $this->session->unset_userdata('lastid');
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.